# how do exchanges move their users assets?

Tags: solidity, addresses, exchanges, cryptography, hd-wallets

do big exchanges move their users assets from HD wallets different dresses to a main wallet address ? to eventually move it to cold wallet ? if the answer is YES how do they do it? that's a lot of on chain transactions !!!